# Is it safe to have sensitive Information like passwords or hash pepper in HashMap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I am trying to find out if my approach of using secrets in my application can be not a good practice or potential security issue.

Our deployment pipeline will fetch the secrets from vault and provided to application as an environment variable which will be in the format of JSON string. When I have to access one secret in my application,
I am letting @Value convert JSON String into Map KV's and using .get() to get desired value. Please let me know if I this can be issue or better way to do this.

```
SECRETS - Provided as Environment variable
Ex: export SECRETS = "{"hello":"world","foo":"bar"}"

@Bean
public Object method(@Value("#{${SECRETS}}") Map<String, String> secrets) {
    new Object(secrets.get("hello"));  //passing secret as constructor argument
}
```

Comment: Having it in maps is no more or less safe than having it elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed.  Furthermore, any question about whether something is "safe" needs to start by explaining the attack vectors you want to protect against.  For example, if you assume that the hacker is able to attach a debugger to the running application, then absolutely nothing is safe.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how security works. You can't point at measured and code styles and claim that "this one is 94.1835% secure" or some such nonsense.

Instead, you first create thread models: Which attack vector are you trying to protect against?

Note that there are attack vectors that are incredibly had to protect against (read: Costs millions and imposes a *lot* of inconvenience on legitimate users). That is, "Security at any cost" is a stupid thing to say and not something you can put in practice.

That is *why* you want those attack vectors: As a programmer and a technically capable operator you can explain precisely which attack vector(s) a given application is capable of defending against and which ones they aren't, as well as which measure(s) will stop a given attack vector and how much they cost.

It's up to a product decision maker to take the list of attack vectors and cost(s) to mitigate them, and decide which ones to mitigate and which ones to leave. There will always be some you leave out.

For storing sensitive authentication data like this, the attack vectors fall in 3 broad strokes:

#### Outside parties that do not have physical access to the machine the code runs on, nor are they capable of logging in on that machine as either a 'root' user or the user under which the server runs

The only way they are going to read that map is if you write code that somehow leaks it. For example, you have some web page endpoint that is programmed so that if I go to, say, `https://www.user16353001.com/getAuthInfo?k=hello`, that it gives `world` back, i.e. you programmed it that way.

You solve that by.. not doing that.

#### Parties that have physical access to the machine, or can log in as root, or can log in as the user under which the process runs

Then you're in deep trouble and in general **nothing is safe anyway** - if an attacker can do that, you have far bigger problems than 'oh dear they can read the auth map'. However, there is a **vanishingly exotic** situation where you may still care about this.

**IF** the attacker can access the box pretty much whenever they want and for long periods of time, no tricks in the code are ever going to solve the problem. So we now pile yet another exotic condition on top of more exotic conditions and, let's say we want to protect against an attacker that has physical access / root / user access, but only intermittently.

And then we pile a third condition on top and that is: You, the server code, only need the auth info sometime during the bootup procedure and then you don't need it any more.

In this **one** case there is a thing you can do: Store the data as a `new char[]`, and then explicitly zero out the char array when you're done with it. In addition, do not **ever** let the password be transformed into any other data type. Never turn it into a string, bytebuffer, or anything else.

This is in fact **why** e.g. `Console`'s [`readPassword()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()) method returns a `char[]` and not a `String`. For this one exotic-wrapped-in-an-exotic-wrapped-in-an-exotic case. I think it's a ridiculous measure no sane person who judges attack vectors could possibly identify as reasonable to spend even one smidge of time on, but then that's why I said: You just explain the technical parts and code it. Someone else can make the call, even a bad one.

The reason why `char[]` works and nothing else will, and only if you *never* convert that char[] to anything else, is because e.g. a string is an object that lives on the heap and will continue to do so until the garbage collector gets rid of it, and that might be **days** from now. Java's garbage collectors that run immediately once some object turns into garbage. They only run when neccessary, which can be 'never' if you have a simple app and tons of memory. In addition you can't tell java: Please garbage collect this object, **right now**. Even `System.gc()` doesn't guarantee anything. So, once it's a string, there's a chance that the password stays in your process memory for days and there's nothing you can do about it. If it's in `char[]` form you can zero out that array and have very slightly more guarantee that the password is now no longer in your process memory. Which is worth almost nothing, so, mostly, this doesn't matter.

Just calling out that it is the one thing you can do, useless as it is, and why some auth stuff takes/provides `char[]` instead of `String`.

### TPM / T2 systems

There's one final thing you can do to truly secure it way down, protect even against long-lasting root access: Security chips.

On windows, there's the TPM chip that most modern windows-targeted hardware has. On macs there's the T2, I think baked into the Mx family of apple's own chips these days.

These systems are extremely hard to integrate from java code (you'd need some native bridges), basically nobody does this, and the auth protocol **has to be** a challenge/response affair (i.e. a simple password cannot be protected using TPM infrastructure), further complicating matters.

If you can jump through all those hoops, you can set up a system whereby the secret is loaded into the TPM/T2 chip, by the TPM/T2 chip, and even a few million dollars of hardware cannot get it out, by anybody.

You need to look really really far to find implementations of this principle. It'll also be extremely complicated to try to do this with java, and most existing auth protocols simply cannot be adopted to use these. So, you can probably forget about their existence.